# How do you permanently modify a method that you are defining?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to have "backwards_string!" permanently modify a String object by capitalizing the even characters and then reversing the string.

```
class String
    def backwards_string!
        reverse!
        scan(/..?/).map(&:capitalize) * ''
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace`

```
class String
    def backwards_string!
        reverse!
        replace(scan(/..?/).map(&:capitalize) * '')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class String
    def backwards_string!
        length.times {|i| self[i] = self[i].upcase if i.even? }
        reverse!        
    end
end
```